# Regex to match words in any order

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm looking to find a regular expression that will match a list of words in any order,
unless a word that is not listed is encountered. The code would be something to the
sort of

```
// match one two and three in any order
$pattern = '/^(?=.*\bone\b)(?=.*\btwo\b)(?=.*\bthree\b).+/';
$string = 'one three';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches); // should match array(0 => 'one', 1 => 'three')

// match one two and three in any order
$pattern = '/^(?=.*\bone\b)(?=.*\btwo\b)(?=.*\bthree\b).+/';
$string = 'one three five';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches); // should not match; array()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
$pattern = '/\G\s*\b(one|two|three)\b(?=(?:\s\b(?:one|two|three)\b)*$)/';
$string = 'one three two';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

`\G` resets the matching after each match.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => three
    [2] => two
)
```

[viper-7 demo](http://viper-7.com/m7y4Z1).

Comment: anyway to get it to remove duplication? aka `one three two two` Thanks Jerry, +1 for a great answer and accepted

Comment: @ehime Oh in a string like `one three two two` you want the matches appearing only once? That makes it a little easier, though you get the whole string in `$matches[0]` and what you're looking for in the other elements of the array: [viper-7 update](http://viper-7.com/5JNE0l). Though I guess you can simply remove that first element after getting the whole array.

Comment: Yeah that would be seriously awesome, I'm doing this for network matching and if I don't have to filter stuff out later it would be awesome.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, would you mind taking a quick look and telling me what happened Jerry? http://viper-7.com/MprSFi

Comment: @ehime Aw, I forgot that this works more like a password validating thing, so it's making sure all the words are present in the string :( That won't do, unfortunately. The one in my answer still works, except there's this filtering issue you mentioned later hmm. I'll try to get something.

Comment: Ok, just a heads up, this is being passed in as a filter_var_array regex, I'll post up a pastebin in a second to show you how.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m8a3ZVn4 and thanks for adding the extra bit of time, its appreciated

Comment: This is actually working brilliantly right now, thanks so much Jerry!

Comment: @ehime Is it? I don't understand how `filter_var_array` works ^^; Because even a simple regex seem to return nothing [here](http://viper-7.com/0CxMLE) :( If it works however, I'm glad!

Comment: yeah what the filter I sent you will do is return null on a catch, so if there is for instance `foo` in the list, it will return a NULL operator back marking it as a flag. Otherwise it returns all of the matches that I need. =) Amazing little method, I tell you sir ;) hats off to you.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this without the need for look ahead.

Try a pattern like

```
^(one|two|three|\s)+?$
```

the above will match `one`, `two`, `three`, or a `\s` white space character.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to match `" "`

Comment: This is actually pretty close, I get a second array param for the last match: http://pastebin.com/ysYmLrTP +1 for almost nailing it

Comment: @ehime This is a working solution and to get only a single element you need to use a non-capturing group like this: `^(?:one|two|three|\s)+?$`.

Comment: @Sniffer I had to change it back, as it changes the nature of the pattern.

Comment: @ehime The above pattern is flawed as it only returns the last element matching the capture group.  The answer by Jerry is probably fit to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
$pattern = '/^(?:\s*\b(?:one|two|three)\b)+$/';
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is required to have all of  'one, two, three'
and there not be a different word  this works.

```
 # ^(?!.*\b[a-zA-Z]+\b(?<!\bone)(?<!\btwo)(?<!\bthree))(?=.*\bone\b)(?=.*\btwo\b)(?=.*\bthree\b)

 ^ 
 (?!
      .* \b [a-zA-Z]+ \b 
      (?<! \b one )
      (?<! \b two )
      (?<! \b three )
 )
 (?= .* \b one \b )
 (?= .* \b two \b )
 (?= .* \b three \b )
```